# How to transform a two dimensional normal distribution into a two dimensional lognorm distribution in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

My question has two parts one is how can i define a two dimensional lognorm function that takes in x and y positions and returns a lognorm output. I want to then take this output and use it as the z dimension in a 3d surface plot. So my goal is to plot a two dimensional lognorm distribution as a 3d surface plot. Any help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to define it, it is provided for you by the library you are using `from scipy.stats import lognorm`

Comment: i understand, but how can i use that to plot a two dimensional lognorm? and then use that for the 3d surface, thank you so much for replying with help

Comment: GIYF
https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots
Provide slice as 3 vectors having the same length then z[i][j]=f(x[i],y[j])

Comment: ok so my x and y would look something like:  x = np.linspace(-90, 90, 400) and y = np.linspace(-90, 90, 400). How could i get the z values which would correspond to the lognorm outputs?

Comment: I must admit statistical ignorance of your specific problem, but from what I can tell only lognorm operates on the 2d case, so you need to generate cross sections of the target surface.

Comment: If you explain your problem in explicit detail in terms of your desired input, outputs and intermediates I might be able to help.  If you have some clean code you can post that would also be helpful.

Comment: i apologize this is uncharted territory for me but i'll try what you've suggested. I'd like an example of how to do it if you could provide one but thank you for your help none the less

Comment: ok so my x and y coordinates are between -90 and 90 along both the x and y axis. I'd like to produce a lognorm response centered at x = 10 and y = 0. so then i can plot the result as a 3d surface, this is meant to represent a topographical map of a part of the human brain. i dont have much code to post here as I'm fairly stuck at this point. I know how to set up my plot via the x and y coordinates but i dont know how to get the corresponding log norm z coordinates. i use lognorm due to the strong tail the distribution has, since it models the part of the brain's receptive field quite well.

Comment: as a starting point I suppose we can use a two dimensional normal distribution and then transform it into a lognorm distribution, would that make sense. thank you so much for taking the time to help genuinely

Comment: Will you centre the falloff in the centre of your net, and then lathe?  If so, you need to convert to polar coordinates,  The centre becomes the origin of the 2D case, then the euclidean distance from the centre projected in the xy-plane is the t-value at which to sample the lognorm in 2D.  So sample your whole linespace by converting each point to the corresponding polar and extract the above into the z.

Comment: alright that makes sense, would you be able to provide a sample code of the above explanation? that way i can ensure i am doing as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the gist of it, I haven't tested it, but the logic is not too complicated . it might also be vectorizable for a speed up, but you have to map your linspaces into a single long array of 2D vectors.

```
dx = xMax - xMin
dy = yMax - yMin
c= (dx+dx/2.0,dy+dy/2.0)
z=np.array(shape=(N,M))
#Lets use a cartersian input vector space instead of polar
for i in range(len(xlinspace)):
    for j in range(len(ylinspace)):
        p=(xlinspace[i],ylinspace[j])
        d= np.norm(p-c) # produce a distance form the centre for the smapled point
        t=d #I'm just renaming distance to t to make it clear, this is an extra step as far as the program is concerned.
        #Now put your lognorm logic here, i'll use f as a placeholder function
        z[i][j]=f(t)
#You now have a 2d array of z outputs
```

Comment: thank you so much i will definitely use this as a framework, one final question, for the lognorm logic i can simply use the scipy lognorm function and input into it the t values correct? Again thank you very much for all your help

Comment: According to the invocations shown at the bottom of the page two inputs are necessary, data and a sigma(stddev) and you must decide how you want to use it, for example, do you need a pdf or a cdf, or perhaps are you fitting data.  You must select a specific invocation from the module e.g. `lognrom.pdf(data,s)`. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html

Comment: i see! also is the np norm a simple calculation for distance? so can we use any method for distance for example euclidean, since the np.norm is not a function

Comment: You can compute euclidean distance using the pythagorean theorem of arbitrary large dimensions.  Subtracting two vectors from one another produces a vector centred (0,0), pointing to a, having magnitude equivalent to the distance between a and b, so if you ask for the norm, it equates to the euclidean distance, it's a nice shorthand.

Comment: please look at the answer below to see how I implemented it

Answer (score 0):

```
dx = 90 - (-90)
dy = 90 - (-90)
c = [dx + dx/2.0, dy+dy/2.0]
z = np.zeros((400, 400))
x = np.linspace(-90, 90, 400)
y = x.copy()
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        p =[x[i], y[j]]
        d = math.sqrt((p[0]-c[0])**2 + (p[1]-c[1])**2)
        t = d

        z[i][j] = lognorm.pdf(t, 1.2)




fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
ax.plot_surface(x,y, z, cmap = 'viridis')



plt.show()
```

ok so here's the code i;ve written and the output is for sure getting there but it looks a bit odd. I;ve attached it for you, please see if you can provide any guidance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYzrE.png)

Comment: awiebe please look when you get a chance